# CMake: How to pass mode dependent compile flags to nvcc in visual studio environment

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, cmake, cuda

I am recently using CMake to compile my CUDA codes, but don't know how to pass different compile flags to nvcc, in Debug or Release mode. I wish I can specify something as follows,

```
set(CUDA_GENE_FLAGS_DEBUG "-gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 -gencode arch=compute_37,code=sm_37")
set(CUDA_GENE_FLAGS_RELEASE "-Xptxas -O3 -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 -gencode arch=compute_37,code=sm_37")
```

So when I specify Debug or Release mode in visual studio, these flags can be chosen automatically. Can anyone give me a hand on this? Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I encountered a same problem while compiling linking OpenMP for a CUDA program.

According to the [latest CMake document for FindCUDA](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/module/FindCUDA.html) here, you should try these three variables: `CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS`, `CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS_DEBUG` and `CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS_RELEASE`.

But it didn't work for me and then I found another [reference](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/building-cuda-applications-cmake/).

If none of above variables work, try to use `CMAKE_CUDA_FLAGS` like this for a workaround:

```
set(CMAKE_CUDA_FLAGS ${YOUR_FLAGS})
```